# Play Framework Action.async WS within another function

Tags: web-services, scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I'm having a bit of a dilemma with incorporating a web service within an Action using **Play 2.3**. In this "ping" action I am first checking to see if the requester has a session token. If they do, the application returns the string "pong" to the browser.

```
  def ping = Action { request =>
    request.session.get("token") match {
      case Some(token) => {
        Ok("pong")
      } case None => Unauthorized("error")  
    } 
  }
```

Now, if I add a call to another web service in the action like this:

```
  def ping = Action.async { request =>
    request.session.get("email") match {
      case Some(email) => {
        WS.url("http://localhost:8080/ping").get.map { response =>
          Ok(response.json.as[JsString].value)
        }
      } case None => Unauthorized("error")  
    } 
  }
```

I end up with a mismatch, the matcher for None (someone who does not have a session token) is not within a Future.

```
  type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.Result required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
```

My only option right now is to get rid of the **None** in the switch. The compiler warns me that this logic is prone to error... but it will compile. I assume I'm doing everything wrong here, both for async ws call and the session variable handling.

Can anyone suggest how I could fix up this ping action so that it can handle both the switch for session variable and the async. I'm just starting to grasp Scala Concurrency/Futures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Action.async` expects a `Future[Result]`, but `Unauthorized("error")` is just a `Result`. You can solve this by simply making it a successful `Future`.

```
def ping = Action.async { request =>
    request.session.get("email") match {
        case Some(email) => {
            WS.url("http://localhost:8080/ping").get.map { response =>
                Ok(response.json.as[JsString].value)
            }
        } 
        case None => Future.successful(Unauthorized("error"))
    } 
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect logical sense. It seems forced to wrap the case in a Future, but, as I said in the post, Futures are still pretty mysterious to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `case None` with:

```scala
// ...
case None => Future.successful(Unauthorized("error"))
```

So the type will be future of result in both cases (there successfully return an HTTP error as result).